# Adding all axis labels to a d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using this template (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) to build a graph using d3. I would like to add all the x axis labels. As for the example; the author doesn't add all of them.

When I read the tutorial; It recommended to change this one

```
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));
```

What should I do ?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqLgowh1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `.ticks(5)` call from your axis function to start with.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");
```

This would display all the labels in the scale. But you'll notice that text will overlap. So you'll need to select all the labels in the axis and rotate them as well as re-adjust margins for a better look.

Check out

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522

for rotating the axis labels.